# Looking to ask question on OCR tool recommendation - where would I ask this on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking to build a license plate detector, but I am struggling to get the last part of the process working i.e. a character classifier for each character I've segmented from the license plate.

If I would like to inquire on a Stack Exchange website on what the best possible tools to use for this would be, where would I ask, or is Stack Exchange the completely wrong place for this type of question (and if so which site could I use to ask this type of question)?

Comment: Programming library recommendations are on-topic on [softwarerecs.se] *if* they are sufficiently specified.